# Eclipse Back Up

Tags: github

I want a way to back up my Eclipse programs remotely in case something happens to my laptop. I know git hub could be a potential option, but can I make sure that the files I post to a git hub repo can only be viewed by me and no one else? Or what are other option for this?

Comment: There are [several other options](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-hosting-services-compared/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pay $7 per month to create private repositories, or encrypt your files before push to a public repository.